# Rails complex search condition over two associated models

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, range

OK. So I have an Vehicle model and Schedule model. Vehicle `has_many :schedules` (Schedule `belongs_to :vehicle`). Schedule has the following structure:

```
id | (date)from_date | (date)to_date | (bool)available | (int)vehicle_id
```

User specifies days range: `from_date` and `to_date` and I need to return the Vehicles, which has ALL the days **available**

Example (With one vehicle for simplicity):

```
[
  (id: 1, from_date: "10/10/2012", to_date: "13/10/2012, available: true, vehicle_id: 1),
  (id: 2, from_date: "14/10/2012", to_date: "15/10/2012", available: true, vehicle_id: 1),
  (id: 3, from_date: "16/10/2012", to_date: "20/10/2012", available: false, vehicle_id: 1)
]
```

-Test Queries:

1) `from_date: "12/10/2012", to_date: "15/10/2012"`, => result: Vehicle

2) `from_date: "11/10/2012", to_date: "17/10/2012"`, => result: [] (Because 16.10 and 17.10 are *not* available)

3) `from_date: "01/11/2012", to_date: "30/11/2012"`, => result: Vehicle (If not a single day from the date range is in Schedule list - Vehicle is still returned (Considered available). So the only exception - If any day from the range happens to be **not_available** - the Vehicle should be rejected)

How can this be accomplished? Sorry if it is too complex.

Comment: Is Object the actual name of the model?  What does it represent?

Comment: No it isn't. I've named it so, for sake of simplicity (Because it really doesn't matter what object it is). In my particular case it represents Vehicle object (which has a rent Schedules)

Comment: I renamed it to Vehicle - Object is a built-in Ruby class so it makes it more confusing, not less!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it with scopes:

```
# schedule.rb

scope :unavailable, where(available: false)

def self.between(from_date, to_date)
  where "from_date <= ? AND to_date >= ?", to_date, from_date
end


# vehicle.rb

def self.available_between(from_date, to_date)
  id_not_in Schedule.unavailable.between(from_date, to_date).map(&:vehicle_id)   
end

def self.id_not_in(ids)
  return all if ids.empty?
  where "id NOT IN (?)", ids
end
```

Then you can just call `Vehicle.available_between "2012-10-12", "2012-10-15"`

This relies on two observations:

- The schedules that are available don't matter. Just find the schedules marked unavailable, then find all vehicles that are *not* related to those schedules.
- You can test if two date ranges A and B overlap by checking that both the following are true

  - the start date of A is *before* the end date of B
  - the end date of A is *after* the start date of B

NB I used Ruby 1.9 syntax in the `unavailable` scope, if you're on 1.8 you need to change `available: false` to `:available => false`.

Comment: Wow. Very neat one! I'll definitely take a look at it more precisely! Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Doesn't seem to be working. id NOT IN (NULL) - so it always returns empty array :(

Comment: Well, the neat thing about splitting it up into scopes is that you can test each part individually. Does `Schedule.unavailable` return all the unavailable scopes? Does `Schedule.between("2012-10-12", "2012-10-15")` return all the schedules between 12 and 15 October? Are your date columns actually stored as dates and not just strings (I ask because you're writing "dd/mm/yyyy" when databases usually use "yyyy-mm-dd")?

Comment: 1) Yes - Schedule.unavailable returns all the unavailable scopes.
2) Schedule.between returns 1 unavailable Schedule.
3) Yeah, they are stored as Dates. This cant be the source of the problem, since pts 1 and 2 work! :) The Problem is: When I specify the range, that has no unavailable schedules (For example I specify Schedule.unavailable "2012-11-01", "2012-"11-30" => it returns [], since there is no matching Schedule (and this is true) for this one, so Vehicle cannot be selected from empty array of id's

Comment: Interesting! So then, does `Schedule.unavailable.between(from_date, to_date).map(&:vehicle_id)` return an array of vehicle ids?

Comment: Ah. I did not expect that not to work (should have tested it... my bad)! Updated my answer :)

Comment: =) Thank you once again! Now it is fine!

Comment: one last thing - can I have it working on some subset of data (Vehicles?) rather than all of the Vehicles from the database. Suppose I have vehicels = Vehicles.find(:all, :conditions => "bla bla"), can I apply .where or something to process it just the same way ?

Comment: Yeah, totally, just chain 'em up: `Vehicle.where(type: 'SUV').available_between(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# for each vehicle find all the rows where vehicle is available for given dates
available_schedules = Schedule.where("vehicle_id = ? and from_date <= ? and to_date >= ? and available = ?",vehicle_id,from_date,to_date,true)

# start by assuming that schedule hasn't been found
schedule_found = false

# for each date in you range check all the available schedules if there is one matching your date. 
# If you find a single schedule set schedule_found flag to true and break from loop else loop through all the available schedules.
# Now if schedule_found is true then make it false (to be used by next date) else return [] as per your requirement.  
(from_date..to_date).each do |dt|
    available_schedules.each do |schedule|
            if schedule.from_date <= dt and schedule.to_date >= dt
                    schedule_found = true
                    break
            end
    end

    if schedule_found
            schedule_found = false
    else
            return []
    end
end

# If your code manages to reach here then it means all the dates in range have an available schedule, so just return Vehicle object
return Vehicle.find(vehicle_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a schedule group that DOESN'T meet the condition of being outside the range of availabilities..  and if you can't find one.. that's your winner

WARNING: NOT TESTED

v = Vehicle.join(:schedules).where('vehicles.id not in (select vehicle_id from schedules where schedules.from_date > :date and schedules.to_date < :date)', :date => date)